# Syntax error checking if file exists

Tags: bash, rhel, amazon-ec2, aws, amazon-linux

A bash script running in Amazon Linux 2 is trying to test if a file exists.  Then if it does exist, the script should delete the file.

The following error gets thrown every time the script runs.  What needs to change in the script in order for the error to no longer be a problem?

```
File "/home/username/write_hosts.sh", line 3
    if [ -f /home/username/hosts ]
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the entire script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -f /home/username/hosts ]
then
    rm /home/username/hosts
fi

declare -a arr_of_tags=("this-master" "this-worker")

for i in "${arr_of_tags[@]}"
do
   echo ["$i"] >> /home/username/hosts
   echo "About to test ip array for $i"
   declare -a arr_of_ips=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2 --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress" --filter "Name=tag:Name,Values=$i" --output=text)
   for j in "${arr_of_ips[@]}"
   do 
      echo "$j" >> /home/username/hosts
   done
done
```

---

**User Suggestions**

---

Per @steve's suggestion, I got the following:

```
[username@ip-10-0-0-73 ~]$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-koji-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/username
```

Note: The contents of `/var/spool/mail/username` are not new.  Just the same error shown at top above.

Per @Jesse_b's suggestion:

```
[username@ip-10-0-0-73 ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/username/.local/bin:/home/username/bin

[username@ip-10-0-0-73 ~]$ sudo bash write_hosts.sh
write_hosts.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
write_hosts.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
write_hosts.sh: line 9: $'\r': command not found
write_hosts.sh: line 11: $'\r': command not found
write_hosts.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'rite_hosts.sh: line 13: `do
```

---

**Solution**

---

I changed the script to the following, then I ran `dos2unix` on the script before calling the script.  The result is a working script now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rm -f /home/username/hosts

declare -a arr_of_tags=("this-master" "this-worker")

for i in "${arr_of_tags[@]}"
do
   echo ["$i"] >> /home/username/hosts
   echo "About to test ip array for $i"
   declare -a arr_of_ips=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2 --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress" --filter "Name=tag:Name,Values=$i" --output=text)
   for j in "${arr_of_ips[@]}"
   do
      echo "$j" >> /home/username/hosts
   done
done
```

Also, to confirm @steve's suspicion, I see that python was being invoked in a cronjob definition, which I have corrected as follows:

```
echo '* * * * * lnxcfg bash /home/username/write_hosts.sh' | sudo tee  /etc/cron.d/refresh_hosts
```

Before the correction, `python` was being called in the preceding line and not `bash`.  So I am marking @steve's answer as accepted.

Comment: What is the contents of your `PATH`?  What if you run the script with `bash script.sh`?

Comment: How (exactly) are you running this script?

Comment: Your script has windows style line endings in it, you will need to run dos2unix on it or similar.   This likely caused it to not understand your hashbang and your default interpreter is python.

Comment: @Jesse_b See the OP for the solution, to which you contributed with your `dos2unix` suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you're getting suggests you're actually running it via Python.

Has some fool overwritten your bash binary with python ?  Try running `bash --version`.

Example

```
[steve@centos ~]$ cat x1
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -f /home/username/hosts ]
then
    rm /home/username/hosts
fi
[steve@centos ~]$ ./x1
[steve@centos ~]$ python x1
  File "x1", line 3
    if [ -f /home/username/hosts ]
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[steve@centos ~]$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

[steve@centos ~]$
```

As an aside, I'm a fan of a simple `rm /home/username/hosts 2>/dev/null` rather than the `if/then/rm/fi` approach.  i.e. try to delete it regardless of whether it exists.

Comment: I posted results of `bash --version` at the end of the OP, per your request.

Comment: Why not use `rm -f /home/username/hosts`?

Comment: Also, the `2` in `rm /home/username/hosts 2>/dev/null` is throwing a separate error.  Is the `2` a typo?

Comment: @CodeMed: It is not but you are almost certainly using python to interpret a bash script.

Comment: I'd recommend `rm -f` rather then just `rm` so it never asks for confirmation, and never objects if the file doesn't exist. Then there's no need for the _stderr_ redirect either.

Comment: @roaima See the OP for the solution, to which you contributed with your `rm -f` suggestion.

Comment: @steve See the OP for the solution.  Given how the error was resolved, can you please explain how Python is involved?  If you still think that Python is involved.  Thank you.

Comment: See my comment at end of OP regarding how I found python and fixed that aspect of the problem.  Thank you and +1 for helping to diagnose.